# How to always start a new job instance for each run when using spring batch with spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

While using spring batch with spring boot, we will get a fat jar which contains all of my spring batch jobs, I want to be able to trigger a specific job from the command line by specifying the job name, the problem is that spring batch detects the job completed, so it will only run the job once, with spring boot, we can specify the name using `--spring.batch.job.names=jobToRun`, the problem is how can I make it always start a new instance and still be able to use this mechanism to pass a job name to run.

I didn't configure a JobLauncher, so I guess it's using the default `JobLauncherCommandLineRunner`, All I currently configured is:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
}
```

With this configuration, I can run the job from the command line:

```
java -jar batch.jar --spring.batch.job.names=job1ToRun
```

How can I start a new instance for every run with a similiar mechanism? I need to specify a job name from the command line to choose a job to run.

Comment: How exactly are you launching the job? Some code snippets of you launching the job & your JobLauncher configuration might be helpful.

Comment: I tried to give an answer to you question. It might not be as detailed as you hoped. If you need any more detailed information please consult the spring-batch documentation or post enough of your code, so the behaviour can be reproduced.

Answer (score 0):

From the [spring-batch documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/configureJob.html)

> **The CommandLineJobRunner**
>
> Because the script launching the job must kick off a Java Virtual Machine, there needs to be a class with a main method to act as the primary entry point. Spring Batch provides an implementation that serves just this purpose: CommandLineJobRunner. It's important to note that this is just one way to bootstrap your application, but there are many ways to launch a Java process, and this class should in no way be viewed as definitive. The CommandLineJobRunner performs four tasks:
>
> - Load the appropriate ApplicationContext
> - Parse command line arguments into JobParameters
> - Locate the appropriate job based on arguments
> - Use the JobLauncher provided in the application context to launch the job.

A very basic example of how you could do this:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    JobLauncher jobLauncher = ctx.getBean(JobLauncher.class);
    String jobName = args[0] // assuming args[0] is the jobName
    JobParameters jobParameters = createJobParameters(args)
    Job jobInstance = ctx.getBean(jobName, Job.class);          
    jobLauncher.run(jobInstance, jobParameters);                   
}

private static JobParameters createJobParameters(String[] args) {
    // TODO: Create & return the needed parameters 
}
```